# MYSQL total count more than 1 table total result

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. I want to select *count* in 1 result, like:

```
table1=1000 records + table2=400 records + table3=200 records = 1600
```

`1600` is the one result I want back from the server.

MySQL inner join perhaps? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide tables structure?

Comment: `SELECT SUM counting FROM(SELECT COUNT(*) as counting  FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) as counting  FROM t2 UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) as counting  FROM t3 )x`

Comment: the tables all have diffrent structure i only want to select count (*) in a total result query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
select sum(c) from (
  select count(*) as c from table1 
  union 
  select count(*) as c from table2 
  union 
  select count(*) as c from table3 
) tmp
```

That'll give you the total.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  (
    select count(columnname) from table1 

  ) + (
    select count(columnname) from table2

  )+ (
    select count(columnname) from table3

  )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...,

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1
        )+
        (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tbl2
        )+
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl3
        )   as 'AllCount'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1 ) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 ) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl3 )) AS TotalRecords
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
    ((select count(*) from table1) + (select count(*) from table2) + (select count(*) from table3))
 as totalCount;
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your responses I have 3 tables and i want to select a count in 1 single result

still i get results back like this

count1 count2 count3
1235   134    234

**and this is not what i want a total one result**

Comment: try this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777541/mysql-total-count-more-than-1-table-total-result/27777607#27777607

Comment: i did, but not getting expected result but the http://stackoverflow.com/a/27777654/3186834 works fine thank you for your help